# Relationship between $ax+by=c$ is and its slope $-\frac{a}{b}$.

Tags: calculus

I can't understand why the slope of $ax+by=c$ is equal to $-\frac{a}{b}$ and what $-\frac{a}{b}$ has to do with the $\tan(\theta)$?

[image]

How can the line be equal to the minus $\frac{-a}{b}$?

Comment: When you increase $x$ by $1$ you decrease $y$ by $-\frac ab$. Draw an appropriate right-angled triangle with base $1$ on the graph of your straight line, and mark the angle $\theta$.

Comment: @projectilemotion: Consider moving your comment to an answer so we may select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the equation of a straight line is given by $y=mx+d$ where $m$ is the slope and $d$ is the $y$-intercept. Thus, all we must do to find the slope is rearrange the equation you have:
$$ax+by=c \iff by=-ax+c \iff y=\color{red}{-\frac{a}{b}}x+\frac{c}{b}$$
Therefore, by comparison with the general equation of a straight line, this gives us the slope of $m=-\frac{a}{b}$.

---

Thus, we know that the slope of the normal to that line is $m_{\text{normal}}=-\frac{1}{m}=-\frac{1}{\left(-\frac{a}{b}\right)}=\frac{b}{a}$. Therefore, we have:
$$m_{\text{normal}}=\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}=\frac{\sin{\theta}}{\cos{\theta}}=\tan{\theta}=\frac{b}{a}$$

Answer (score 1):

> How can the line be equal to the minus $\frac{-a}{b}$?

If $b$ is non-zero, $-\tfrac{a}{b}$ is a (real) number, of course it's not *equal to* the line - why would it be? The slope is a **number** associated with a (non-vertical) line and it gives information about the line but that doesn't mean a line and its slope are the *same thing*.

Its sign tells you whether the line is increasing (positive slope), decreasing (negative slope) or constant (zero slope) and its absolute value is a measure for the steepness; i.e. the angle $\alpha$ the line makes with respect to the horizontal $x$-axis. More specifically, the slope is equal to $\tan \alpha$, again for non-vertical lines only. In your graph, the angle $\theta$ corresponds to a line normal to given line.

As for arriving at the formula $-\tfrac{a}{b}$; the slope of a line written in the form $y=\color{blue}{m}x+q$ is the number $\color{blue}{m}$; so solve for $y$ and you have the slope. You can do this for $b \ne 0$:
$$ax+by+c=0 \iff y = \color{blue}{-\frac{a}{b}}x-\frac{c}{b}$$

Comment: thank you very much!!!!!!!